# XSL get single value from attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

this is my input xml:

```
 <ns2:resources>
    <ns2:resource path="/ROOT1/path/">
        <ns2:resource path="/function1/param">
            ....
        </ns2:resource>
        <ns2:resource path="/function2/param">
            ....
        </ns2:resource>
        <ns2:resource path="/function3/param">
            ....
        </ns2:resource>
    </ns2:resource>
    <ns2:resource path="/ROOT1/path2/">
        <ns2:resource path="/function1/param">
            ....
        </ns2:resource>
        <ns2:resource path="/function2/param">
            ....
        </ns2:resource>
        <ns2:resource path="/function3/param">
            ....
        </ns2:resource>
    </ns2:resource>
    <ns2:resource path="/ROOT2/pathN/">
        <ns2:resource path="/function1/param">
            ....
        </ns2:resource>
        <ns2:resource path="/function2/param">
            ....
        </ns2:resource>
        <ns2:resource path="/function3/param">
            ....
        </ns2:resource>
    </ns2:resource>
    <ns2:resource path="/ROOT1/path5/">
        <ns2:resource path="/function1/param">
            ....
        </ns2:resource>
        <ns2:resource path="/function2/param">
            ....
        </ns2:resource>
        <ns2:resource path="/function3/param">
            ....
        </ns2:resource>
    </ns2:resource>
    <ns2:resource path="/ROOT3/pathM/">
        <ns2:resource path="/function1/param">
            ....
        </ns2:resource>
    </ns2:resource>
```

I'd like to get as output a list like this, being my expected result:

```
1 - ROOT1
2 - ROOT2
3 - ROOT3
TOTAL NUMBER OF ROOT IS: 3
```

I tried with some xsl like this:

```
<ul>
  <xsl:for-each xmlns:ns2="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02"
        select="node()/ns2:resources/ns2:resource">
        <xsl:sort xmlns:ns2="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" select="@path" />   

            <li>
                <xsl:value-of   select="substring-before(substring(@path,2),'/')"/>                    
            </li>

    </xsl:for-each>
</ul>
```

But i'm missing the instruction "distinct-values" like to make the list to contain single value of the ROOT-x substring extracted from the path attributes.
Indeed this is what i get:

```
1 - ROOT1
2 - ROOT1
3 - ROOT1
4 - ROOT2
5 - ROOT3
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does "I am missing the instruction `distinct-values()`" mean you are using XSLT 1.0? I have removed the `xslt-2.0` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want an `xsl:key`; this will work with XSLT 1.0

Like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:ns2="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02" exclude-result-prefixes="ns2">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:key name='res' match='/ns2:resources/ns2:resource' use="substring-before(substring(@path,2), '/')" />
    <xsl:template match="/ns2:resources">
        <ul>
          <xsl:for-each select="ns2:resource[count(. | key('res', substring-before(substring(@path,2), '/'))[1]) = 1]">                        
                    <li>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring(@path,2),'/')"/>                    
                    </li>            
            </xsl:for-each>
            <li>                
                TOTAL NUMBER OF ROOT IS: <xsl:value-of select="count(ns2:resource[count(. | key('res', substring-before(substring(@path,2),'/'))[1]) = 1])" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
  PUBLIC "XSLT-compat">
<ul>
   <li>ROOT1</li>
   <li>ROOT2</li>
   <li>ROOT3</li>
   <li>TOTAL NUMBER OF ROOT IS: 3</li>
</ul>
```

http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKwr/2

Comment: it's muenchian method... it works! http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html